# GLEW + VS2010 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, shader, glew

I am running into this issue and don't know what to do ?

```
'abc.exe': Loaded 'D:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvoglv32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
```

earlier I was getting a whole bunch of errors, but the  [microsoft symbols source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy.aspx)  set the issue for all of them except this one file : nvoglv32.dll ; does anybody know how I can resolve this issue or get my hands on the file "nvoglv32.pdb"  ?

Thanks

-A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the OpenGL driver for your NVidia video card.  Yes, you're not going to get the .pdb from Microsoft, they didn't write it.  Getting it from NVidia is very unlikely.  This is not software you want to debug anyway.

Comment: so what can I do ? can I just copy it from another PC  or is it card specific ?

Comment: Not having a .pdb file is quite normal.  You don't have to do anything.  And no, you can't copy it, only NVidia can get you that file.  Hardware vendors don't ever publish the .pdbs for their DLLs, I trust that NVidia is no different.

Comment: Well, can I get the code to compile just based on the dll? the dll is present with me. Any secondary solution/ work around? any help will be of great benefit! Thank you.

Comment: pdb contains debug information and it does not affect your usage of a DLL.  All you need from a DLL is its header/IDL, not the PDB.

Comment: All this information is really great! But I am stuck and don't know how to compile this project. I would much appreciate any clue as to how I can get it to bloody compile!

Comment: I talked to a brick wall for a while and it understood me better.  For the last time: *it is not an error*.  You got your program compiled, it wouldn't start otherwise.  That's it for me, signing off.